# Increasing n_jobs has no effect on GridSearchCV

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, knn

I have setup simple experiment to check importance of the multi core CPU while running sklearn `GridSearchCV` with `KNeighborsClassifier`. The results I got are surprising to me and I wonder if I misunderstood the benefits of multi cores or maybe I haven't done it right.

There is no difference in time to completion between 2-8 jobs. How come ?  I have noticed the difference on a CPU Performance tab. While the first cell was running CPU usage was ~13% and it was gradually increasing to 100% for the last cell. I was expecting it to finish faster. Maybe not linearly faster aka 8 jobs would be 2 times faster then 4 jobs but a bit faster.

**This is how I set it up:**

I am using jupyter-notebook, cell refers to jupyter-notebook cell.

I have loaded MNIST and used `0.05` test size for `3000` digits in a `X_play`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
_, X_play, _, y_play = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.05, random_state=42, stratify=y_train, shuffle=True)
```

In the next cell I have setup `KNN` and a `GridSearchCV`

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
param_grid = [{'weights': ["uniform", "distance"], 'n_neighbors': [3, 4, 5]}]
```

Then I done 8 cells for 8 n_jobs values. My CPU is i7-4770 with 4 cores 8 threads.

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(knn_clf, param_grid, cv=3, verbose=3, n_jobs=N_JOB_1_TO_8)
grid_search.fit(X_play, y_play)
```

**Results**

```
Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  2.0min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.4min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.3min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.3min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=5)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.4min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.4min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=7)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.4min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done  18 out of  18 | elapsed:  1.4min finished
```

**Second test**

Random Forest Classifier usage was much better. Test size was `0.5`, `30000` images.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = [{'n_estimators': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 'max_features': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], 'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy']}]

Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 110.9min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 56.8min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 39.3min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 35.3min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=5)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 36.0min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 34.4min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=7)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 32.1min finished
Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 30.1min finished
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some reasons which **might** be a cause of this behaviour

- With increasing no. of threads, there is an apparent overhead incurred for intializing and releasing each thread. I ran your code on my i7 7700HQ, I saw the following behaviour with each inceasing `n_job`

  - when `n_job=1` and `n_job=2` the time per thread(Time per model evaluation by GridSearchCV to fully train the model and test it) was 2.9s (overall time ~2 mins)
  - when `n_job=3`, time was 3.4s (overall time 1.4 mins)
  - when `n_job=4`, time was 3.8s (overall time 58 secs)
  - when `n_job=5`, time was 4.2s (overall time 51 secs)
  - when `n_job=6`, time was 4.2s (overall time ~49 secs)
  - when `n_job=7`, time was 4.2s (overall time ~49 secs)
  - when `n_job=8`, time was 4.2s (overall time ~49 secs)
- Now as you can see, time per thread increased but overall time seem to decrease (although beyond `n_job=4 the different was not exactly linear) and remained constained with`n_jobs>=6` This is due to the fact that there is a cost incurred with initializing and releaseing threads. See [this github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2757) and [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1565).
- Also, there might be other bottlenecks like data being to large to be broadcasted to all threads at the same time, thread pre-emption over RAM (or other resouces,etc.), how data is pushed into each thread, etc.
- I suggest you to read about Ahmdal's Law which states that there is a theoretical bound on the speedup that can be achieved through parallelization which is given by the formula
  [image]
  Image Source : [Ahmdal's Law : Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)
- Finally, it might be due to the data size and the complexity of the model you use for training as well.

Here is [a blog post](https://blog.pursuitofzen.com/python-parallelism-with-multithreading-and-dask/) explaining the same issue regarding multithreading.