# kfold cross validation wont terminate, stuck at cross_val_score

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation

I am trying to run kfold cross validation. but for some reason, it gets stuck here, it wont terminate from here `accuracies  = cross_val_score(estimator  = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)`
i cant understand whats the problem. and how do i fix it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


import keras
from keras.models import Sequential #Required to initialize the ANN
from keras.layers import Dense #Build layers of ANN
from keras.layers import Dropout


# Evaluating the ANN
import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from keras.models import Sequential #Required to initialize the ANN
from keras.layers import Dense #Build layers of ANN

def build_classifier(): # Builds the architecture, or the classifier
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11, units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))# add layers
    classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))# add layers
    classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'sigmoid', units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
accuracies  = cross_val_score(estimator  = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
mean = accuracies.mean()
variance = accuracies.std()
```

---

Edit
Im on windows 10 using Anaconda with python 3.6.
Dataset : [Drive Link for dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J1rFhDnZgZ6Yn7GT9vRrfw0ha6Spyk-1)
It works perfectly when i set n_jobs = 1 but not when n_jobs = -1

Comment: Have you  tried reducing the `cv` to say 3 or 4 and checking ?

Comment: yeah tried that, but its still stuck

Comment: Seems like this is a [documented issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9927) with scikit-learn and keras. Also looks like there is [currently no solution](https://github.com/AbhayKoushik/LearningDeep/issues/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the `n_jobs = -1`, then all the CPUs are being utlised as per the documentation mentioned [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html). However, you must understand that utilising all the CPUs does not necessarily may lead to reduction in execution time because:

- There is an overhead invovled with creation and allocation of reasources to new threads.
- Also, there might be other bottlenecks like data being to large to be broadcasted to all threads at the same time, thread pre-emption over RAM (or other resouces,etc.), how data is pushed into each thread, etc.
- Also multithreading in Python has various shortcomings, see [here](https://opensourceforu.com/2011/01/python-threading-and-its-caveats/) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-sometime-get-a-crash-freeze-with-n-jobs-1-under-osx-or-linux).

You can check out a similar issue with GridSearchCV and parallization [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993867/increasing-n-jobs-has-no-effect-on-gridsearchcv/50996992#50996992).

Also, as mentioned by @ncfith, there is no current solution for this problem.

**References**

- [Why do I sometime get a crash/freeze with n_jobs > 1 under OSX or Linux?](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-sometime-get-a-crash-freeze-with-n-jobs-1-under-osx-or-linux)
- [Similar issue with numpy on MacOS](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5752)